# How to decode OBD-2 data from Hyundai Ioniq EV

Tags: obd-ii

I try to read out OBD-2 data from Hyundai Ioniq Electro (Version 28kWh), using a Raspberry PI and a Bluetooth ELM327 interface. Connection and data transfer works fine.

For example: sending `2105<cr><lf>` gives a response (`<cr>` is value 0x0d = 13):
`7F2112<cr>7F2112<cr>7F2112<cr>02D<cr>0:6105FFFFFFFF<cr>7F2112<cr>1:00000000001616<cr>2:161616161621FA<cr>3:26480001501616<cr>4:03E82403E80FC0<cr>5:003A0000000000<cr>6:00000000000000<cr><cr>>`

The value `C0` in `4:03E82403E80FC0` seems to be the State of charge (SOC) display value:
`C0` -> 192 -> 192/2 % = 96%

There are some tables for decoding available (see https://github.com/JejuSoul/OBD-PIDs-for-HKMC-EVs/tree/master/Ioniq%20EV%20-%2028kWh), but how to use these tables?

For example sending `2101<cr><lf>` gives the response:

```
02C<cr>
0:6101FFFFF800<cr>
01E<cr>
0:6101000003FF<cr>
03D<cr>
0:6101FFFFFFFF<cr>
016<cr>
0:6101FFE00000<cr>
1:0002D402CD03F0<cr>
1:0838010A015C2F<cr>
7F2112<cr>
1:B4256026480000<cr>
1:0921921A061B03<cr>
2:000582003401BD<cr>
2:0000000A002702<cr>
2:000F4816161616<cr>
2:00000000276234<cr>
3:04B84100000000<cr>
3:5B04692F180018<cr>
3:01200000000000<cr>
3:1616160016CB3F<cr>
4:00220000600000<cr>
4:00D0FF00000000<cr>
4:CB0100007A0002<cr>
5:000001F3026A02<cr>
5:5D4000025D4600<cr>
6:D2000000000000<cr>
6:00DECA0000D8E6<cr>
7:008A2FEB090002<cr>
8:0000000003E800<cr>
<cr>
>
```

Please note, that the line feed was added behind every carriage return (`<cr>`) for better readability and is not part of the original data response.

How can I decode temperature, currents, ... from these data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the mistake by myself. The ELM327 description (http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf) explains the AT commands in detail.

The problem on this issue was the mixing of CAN responses from multiple ECU's caused by the `AT H0` command (headers off) in the initialization phase (not described in question). See also [EM327DS.pdf](http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf) page 44 (Multiple Responses).

When using `AT H1` on startup, the responses can be decoded without problem.

**Initialization (with AT H1 = headers on)**

```
AT D\r\n
AT Z\r\n
AT L0\r\n
AT E0\r\n
AT S0\r\n
AT H1\r\n
AT SP 0\r\n
```

**Afterwards communication with ECU's:**

1. Response on first command `0100\r\n`:

```
SEARCHING...\r7EB06410080000001\r7EC06410080000001\r\r>
```

2. Response on second command `2101\r\n`:

```
7EE037F2112\r7ED102C6101FFFFF800\r7EA10166101FFE00000\r7EC103D6101FFFFFFFF\r7EB101E6101000003FF\r7EA2109211024062703\r7EC214626482648A3FF\r7ED2100907D87E15592\r7EB210838011D88B132\r7ED2202A1A7024C0134\r7EA2200000000546900\r7EC22C00D9E1C1B1B1B\r7EB220000000A000802\r7EA2307200000000000\r7ED23050343102000C8\r7EC231B1B1C001BB50F\r7EB233C04B8320000D0\r7EC24B5010000810002\r7ED24047400C8760017\r7EB24FF300000000000\r7ED25001401F387F46A\r7EC256AC100026CB100\r7EC2600E3C50000DE69\r7ED263F001300000000\r7EC27008CC38209015C\r7EC280000000003E800\r\r>
```

3. Response on third command `2105\r\n`:

```
7EE037F2112\r7ED037F2112\r7EA037F2112\r7EC102D6105FFFFFFFF\r7EB037F2112\r7EC2100000000001B1C\r7EC221C1B1B1B1B2648\r7EC2326480001641A1B\r7EC2403E80803E80147\r7EC25003A0000000000\r7EC2600000000000000\r\r>
```

Now every response starts with the id of the ECU. Take attention only to responses starting with `7EC`.

---

**Example:**

Looking for battery current in amps. In the document [Spreadsheet_IoniqEV_BMS_2101_2105.xls](https://github.com/JejuSoul/OBD-PIDs-for-HKMC-EVs/blob/master/Ioniq%20EV%20-%2028kWh/Spreadsheet_IoniqEV_BMS_2101_2105.xls) you find the battery current on:

- response `21` for `2101`: last byte = High Byte of battery current
- response `22` for `2101`: first byte = Low Byte of battery current

So look to the response of `2101\r\n` and search for `7EC21` and `7EC22`: You will find:

- `7EC214626482648A3FF`: take last byte for battery high value -> `FF`
- `7EC22C00D9E1C1B1B1B`: take first byte after `7EC22` for battery low value -> `C0`

The battery current value is: `FFC0`

This value is two complements encoded:
`0xffc0 = 65472 -> 65472 - 65536 = -64 ->` **-6.4A**

Result: the battery is charged with 6.4A

For a coding example see:
https://github.com/greenenergyprojects/obd2-gateway, file [src/obd2/obd2.ts](https://github.com/greenenergyprojects/obd2-gateway/blob/master/server/src/obd2/obd2.ts)